# Mysql Crashing: mysqld got signal 11

Tags: mysql

**Mysql gets crashing in production :**

I have 64 GB RAM with 6 core CPU.

**my.cnf**

```
\[mysqld\]
server-id=1
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
lower-case-table-names=1
slow_query_log=1
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G
block_encryption_mode =aes-256-cbc
wait_timeout=600
interactive_timeout=600
log_timestamps=SYSTEM
max_connections=1000
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
binlog_expire_logs_seconds=1296000
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON
thread_cache_size=1001
group_concat_max_len=10000
log_output=TABLE,FILE

\###Loging...
log-bin-index=/var/lib/mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.index
log_bin  = /var/lib/mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.log

\##audit logging
audit_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/auditlog/audit.log
\#audit_log_rotate_on_size=1024M
\#audit_log_rotations=30
audit_log_policy=QUERIES
audit_log_exclude_accounts=root@localhost
audit_log_format=JSON
```

Error log:

````
```

UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.Thread pointer: 0x7f0278bc96c0Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find outwhere mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something wentterribly wrong...stack_bottom = 7f0dac192d10 thread_stack 0x46000/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x560428bc449d]/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x2fb) [0x560427b6e22b]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12980) [0x7f0e0c5dc980]/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf293ce) [0x560427a113ce]/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf295f2) [0x560427a115f2]/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf29623) [0x560427a11623]/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::finalize_table_conditions()+0xeb) [0x560427a1787b]/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::replace_index_subquery()+0x107) [0x560427a17d27]/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::optimize()+0x2765) [0x560427a2b1b5]/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0xb6) [0x560427a87c46]/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x7b) [0x560427af63eb]/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0x115) [0x560427a87ca5]/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x7b) [0x560427af63eb]/usr/sbin/mysqld(TABLE_LIST::optimize_derived(THD*)+0x40) [0x560427ec9dd0]/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::optimize()+0x46c) [0x560427a28ebc]/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0xb6) [0x560427a87c46]/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x7b) [0x560427af63eb]/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute_inner(THD*)+0x3d) [0x560427a8665d]/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x598) [0x560427a906e8]/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xaae) [0x560427a3346e]/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_instr_stmt::exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*)+0x51) [0x5604279afe71]/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::reset_lex_and_exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0x17b) [0x5604279b1d4b]/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::validate_lex_and_execute_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0xde) [0x5604279b2cfe]/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_instr_stmt::execute(THD*, unsigned int*)+0xc3) [0x5604279b4543]/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_head::execute(THD*, bool)+0x3be) [0x5604279a90de]/usr/sbin/mysqld(sp_head::execute_procedure(THD*, mem_root_deque<Item*>)+0x7e3) [0x5604279ac423]/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_call::execute_inner(THD)+0x136) [0x560427ebf106]/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x598) [0x560427a906e8]/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xaae) [0x560427a3346e]/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x3f9) [0x560427a36d29]/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x15ed) [0x560427a3880d]/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x1c4) [0x560427a39fe4]/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1077020) [0x560427b5f020]/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2640091) [0x560429128091]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7f0e0c5d16db]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7f0e0a7c371f]

Trying to get some variables.Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.Query (7f0278518848): is an invalid pointerConnection ID (thread ID): 242364Status: NOT_KILLED ```
````

**Mysql sql got crash Every alter day don't know what is the issue with this.**

Comment: Please move your question to the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, as SO focuses on programming related questions, not on database operations.

Comment: Same time of day?  Any idea what queries are running when it dies?  Anything useful in the slowlog?

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.